# How to export all categories, products, cms pages etc to another magento installation?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

We have two magento installation for the same shop. One is named **live** and the other is named **staging**.

How can I mirror all products and categories from live with staging?

Do I have to export / import the whole database?

Comment: do you want same copy as live site into staging, right? or you want just category and product data not other data?

Comment: I want categories, products, cms pages, cms blocks etc., basically everything without customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd take a look at Magerun's `db:dump` functionality.

You can run something like `n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="@development"` which will provide a DB dump with customer/order/log data stripped from the SQL export but still include all product/category/core tables.

What I usually run is `n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="@development" --compression=gzip /tmp/database.sql.gz` so it's compressed and then put in `/tmp/` to ensure it doesn't go to Magento's public directory.

More information on Magerun's db:dump functionality & installation can be found [here](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) (There is also a Magento 2 version [here](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2))

*Edit

With this method you will have to update your base URLs and other config once you import the SQL to your staging environment but you can use Magerun to set the config values after the import.

Example:

Create a new admin user staging/password1

```
n98-magerun.phar admin:user:create staging test@example.com password1 Example User
```

Amend default base_urls

```
n98-magerun.phar config:set web/unsecure/base_url http://staging.example.com/
n98-magerun.phar config:set web/secure/base_url http://staging.example.com/
```

Comment: But I think this will also delete all admin users. There are many admins and devs working on staging though, do I have to create them again??

Comment: @Black Actually, admin stripping was added in version 1.100.0 of Magerun. If you download a version below this you won't get this feature. Version 1.99.0 release here - https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/archive/1.99.0.tar.gz

Comment: is there a way to do this without BE admins getting deleted? I just imported my live db with your instructions to staging, but no one can login to the backend anymore.

Comment: @Black See my post above your comment. Basically you'll need to delete Magerun on both your staging and production environments and download the 1.99.0 version which can be found here here - github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/archive/1.99.0.tar.gz - This version doesn't include the `admin_users` table getting stripped on export. Hope that helps!

Comment: I just tried it, but the admin_users table is still getting stripped...

Comment: The versions on the repo seem a bit muddled up so I'm not entirely sure which version we're really getting. I've just pulled the 1.98.0 version from https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun-1.98.0.phar and it seemed to work fine, give that a try.

Comment: The admin table was not stripped with 1.98. Thanks alot!

Comment: Glad we got there in the end, no worries! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement you need to do this things.

1. Copy the database from live to staging.
2. Create one script in magento root with this code. (Ex : test.php)

   ```
   <?php
   $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
   if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
             echo $mageFilename." was not found";
   exit;
   }
   require_once $mageFilename;
   Mage::app();
   Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
   try 
   {

       $customers = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection();

       foreach ($customers as $customer) {
            $customer->delete();
       }
       echo "Customer Delete Sucessfully";
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();

   }
   ?>
   ```
3. Now run this file from browser. (Ex : www.domain.com/test.php)

Comment: Is it not possible to just import the categories, products and cms pages? Do I really have to import the whole database?

Comment: Then you need to find or create custom solution to import only those data. But easy way I already specify above.